# I’m a Non-Rabbi who can grow a full beard. From a Halachic perspective should I grow a beard or not?

Tags: beard

I’ve heard that some Rabbis don’t recommend Bachurim to grow beards, while I’ve also heard that everyone should grow beards.
What are the Halachic perspecectives on this?
(Also, hasn’t the beard entered into the category of Jewish dress, and as such should be a problem to shave it?)

Comment: Are you suggesting that only Jews have beards, such that it's distinctively Jewish? That seems incorrect.

Comment: The Chazon Ish did not approve of *bochurim* shaving. In Radin some *bochurim* had beards. In other Litvisher Yeshivas it was deemed highly off and arrogant for a *bochur* to have a beard (e.g. Slabodka).

Comment: If non-Jews wore Yarmulkes it wouldn’t change anything. Jews have historically had beards as it was very difficult to Halachically not have one. Non-Jews have always been able to shave off their beard

Comment: It's really about personal choice, no? The Torah forbids us to shave certain areas of our face. Some interpret this to mean that one should always keep a beard (and even to never cut it, like Chabad). Personally, if a yeshiva required me to shave my beard, that's not a yeshiva I want to be a part of.

Comment: Why? Also if they required you to wear a certain Kippa?

Comment: Rabbi Winner has a massive book in hebrew (הדרת פנים זקן) all about the beard, bringing many many sources. Not sure if there's a English version. Also another short english extract: https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B084YX5TVT/ref=dbs_a_w_dp_b084yx5tvt